# How to select value from TcxDBLookupComboBox component?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am using Delphi 10.3 Rio and DevExpress 18.1.6 library.

Inside my project I have `TcxDBLookupComboBox` component.

I populate that combo box as you can see here

[image: Populated Combo Box]

But when I select one of values and click on it, nothing happens.

I check properties of that component, but I can't find anything that could help me.

Any idea on how can I achieve that?

Comment: What if you press [Enter] instead of clicking?

Comment: Nothing happens when i press [Enter] key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting that behaviour, you form isn't configured correctly.

Below is an extract from a sample project which is "self contained" in that
it creates its data annd look-up data in code in the Form's FormCreate event.
It works completely correctly - when I click in the DBLookUpcombo list
the value from the selected list entry immediately appears in the `Value`
field of `ClientDataSet1`

```
  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    AField : TField;
  begin
    //  First create some dataset fields
    AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
    AField.FieldName := 'ID';
    AField.FieldKind := fkData;
    AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

    AField := TStringField.Create(Self);
    AField.FieldName := 'Value';
    AField.FieldKind := fkData;
    AField.Size := 40;
    AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

    ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
    ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([1, 'SomeValue']);

    AField := TStringField.Create(Self);
    AField.FieldName := 'luValue';
    AField.FieldKind := fkData;
    AField.Size := 40;
    AField.DataSet := cdsLU;

    cdsLU.CreateDataSet;
    cdsLU.InsertRecord(['One']);
    cdsLU.InsertRecord(['Two']);
    cdsLU.InsertRecord(['Three']);

    DBLookupComboBox1.DataSource := DataSource1;
    DBLookupComboBox1.DataField := 'Value';

    DBLookupComboBox1.KeyField := 'luValue';
    DBLookupComboBox1.ListField := 'luValue';
    DBLookupComboBox1.ListSource := DataSource2;

  end;
```

Remainder of TForm1:

```
  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      DataSource1: TDataSource;
      DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
      DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
      ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
      DBLookupComboBox1: TDBLookupComboBox;  // or TcxDBLookupComboBox
      cdsLU: TClientDataSet;
      DataSource2: TDataSource;
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    public
    end;
```